# Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift

Getting stuck after updating here.

Get "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

On this code:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


        let w = Float(panelWidthTextField!.text!)
        let sw = Float(panelsWideTextField!.text!)
        let pi = Float(panelPitchTextField!.text!)
        let sizew = sizeWidthModel(pw:w!,psw:(sw)!,ptc:pi!)

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        **// Error is on the line under.**
        let swt = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(sizew.width()))!
```

SizeWidthModel:

```
import Foundation

class sizeWidthModel {
var pw:Float
var psw:Float
var ptc:Float

init (pw:Float,psw:Float,ptc:Float){
    self.pw=pw
    self.psw=psw
    self.ptc=ptc
}

func width()->Float {
    return pw*psw/ptc
}

func wswidth()->Float {
    return pw*psw
}
}
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: What is the type of `sizew`? what does `sizeWithModel()` return?

Comment: FYI - every use of `!` in your code means "crash here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the swift3.0

Swift3.0 need to clear the parameter name in the absence of '_' write modification parameters

so use:

```
let swt = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:sizew.width()))!
```

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off classes *must always* start with an upper case letter, that's how you recognize they are Types.

This line `let swt = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(sizew.width()))!` is taking a `Float` converting it to an `NSNumber`, then going through a formatter, to end up as a `String`

Why not just use string interpolation?

`let swt = "\(sizew.width())"`

Comment: Correction, class names *should* start with an uppercase letter. It's a standard, not a requirement.