# Swift migration: Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, migration, xcode8

I am a beginner swift developer and I am trying to migrate my app to Swift 3.

I keep having this error and don't know how to solve it. 
"Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

I am using Swift Validator and my code seems to be the same as the proposed one. 
https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator

My issue is possibly similar to those ones:

[similar issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091776/argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads)

[similar issue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443953/swift-3-error-argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads)

Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot

```
class UpdateContactViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,ValidationDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}


let validator = Validator()
let realm = try! Realm()
var contact_identifier = "1"
var lastSelectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
@IBAction func save_button_hit(sender: AnyObject) {
    // text field validator
    validator.validate(self)
}
```

The error is highlighting "validator.validate(self)"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument labels '(\_:)' do not match any available overloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091776/argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads)

Comment: The github you reference shows that you have to register all of the text fields you are interested in before calling the `validate(self)` function.  You don't show that code above ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Swift 3 introduced mandatory labels for the parameters in a method call. So a call that was previously done as:

`elem.perform(a)`

is now done:

`elem.perform(parameterName: a)`

So the correct would be the following:

`validator.validate(delegate: self)`

Comment: Parameter names can be made optional at the call site if preceded by _ in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix the issue: validator.validate(delegate: self)